# Formatting y-axis tick text plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

The tick text of the y axis in my matplotlib plot has too many decimal digits.
How can I format the text to show two decimal digits only.
I.E. I would like to convert `10.39658602` into `10.40`

I've already tried with:

`ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%5.2f'))`

but the decimal digits are set to 0 (the previous number becomes `10.00`).
Here is some image. Before:

[image]

After:
[image]

Edit: I'm including also an example of the code to reproduce the problem.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
lineObjects = plt.plot(epochs, data1, 'rs',
                       epochs, data2, 'b^',
                       epochs, data3, 'gv',
                       epochs, data4, 'ko', ) 
# also %.2f does not work as intended
ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%5.2f'))
plt.show()
```

I'm using Python 3.6 on Anaconda. `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, `data4` are NumPy `ndarray`s of type `str_`, I've already tried to convert them to `float`, but the results are similar.

Comment: Seems to work for me.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? It's not really clear how the numbers with the long tails come into the plot in the first place. Knowing that however is necessary to provide a suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formatting.

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))
```

Comment: I've tried it, also with the `yaxis` instead of `get_yaxis()` method, but without any luck.